# How do the magnitudes of pulling force F and contact force R between the ball and the hemisphere change

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A small metal ball is being pulled gradually on a fixed frictionless
hemisphere as shown in the figure. Radii of the ball and that of the
pulley are much smaller than that of the hemisphere. As the ball slides
from the bottom to a position close to the top of the hemisphere, how do
the magnitudes of pulling force F and contact force R between the ball
and the hemisphere change?

(a) F increases and R decreases.

(b) F decreases and R increases.

(c) F decreases and R remains unchanged.

(d) F remains unchanged and R decreases.

[image]

According to me ,now as the metal ball will gets pulled . $\theta$ will decrease.

More Force must be applied and contact force should decrease .

$F=mg\cos \theta$

$R=mg\sin \theta$
[image]

Comment: The tension in the cord is not parallel to $mg \cos{\theta}$ everywhere on the hemisphere.

Comment: @RodneyDunning Why not ?

Comment: The $mg \cos \theta$ component will be everywhere tangent to the hemisphere, but the tension in the cord will always point along the cord toward the pulley.